# Elastix and two ISDN lines

Tags: voip, asterisk, pbx

Since I am not an expert on communications, I will describe everything from the user perspective.

We had a PBX with elastix embedded and two ISDN cards in it (we have two isdn lines). The mobo of the elastix stopped working so we setup an external server with elastix and connected the PBX to it using USB (in order to use the isdn cards from the pbx).

Everything works fine except that we cannot use all 4 lines to call at the same time. We can use only two (from the first line). Αlthough we can't use all 4 lines to make calls, we can receive 4 calls at a time!

Is there an easy way to configure elastix to use all lines to make calls?

Elastix `2.2.0`, for the isdn cards we use the driver `dahdi 2.4.1.2` and Asterisk `1.8.7.0`

If I'm missing some info, please ask to provide it.

Comment: I know the general idea is that you have to set a "hunt" or "rollover" for outgoing line selection. Unfortunately I don't know how to configure that in Asterisk. Someone who does know will likely be along though.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately I haven't got any experience with elastix. But from Asterisk point of view each interface should be configured as part of a Zaptel group and when you dial you specify it. For example:

Dial(Zap/g1/${EXTEN})

I suspect that the second interface is part from different group and that's why you can't make the call. However I don't know how elastix' should be configured and can't give you and specific hints. Could you provide some details about your setup?

If it helps, here is a part from a machine I've configured with E1 interface.

zaptel.conf - This is ISDN specific parameters. As your interfaces are working, don't touch it:

```
loadzone=uk
defaultzone=uk

span=1,1,0,ccs,hdb3
bchan=1-15
dchan=16
bchan=17-30
```

zapata.conf - Here we configure group one to represent channels 1-15 and 17-30. In your case - there should be two chanbnels.

```
[channels]
switchtype=euroisdn
signalling=pri_cpe
group=1
channel => 1-15
channel => 17-30
```

If you share how you are trying to make the call (the Dial command) and what error you receive I might be able to help.

Again, the above is Asterisk specific. Please excuse me if it is not relevant for elastix.